# Use CURL in PHP to POST Login to a Remote auth function/php file

Tags: php, html, rest, curl, authentication

I am trying to make a Login system for my script and am stuck at a point.

What I need to do is POST the login details of user he has submitted on login.php (server1) to my backend script's login system verify.php(server2)
The verify.php uses the POST data to validate the login information and actually set cookie and all other things for the backend system.

I am using a 3rd part script on server2 so I cant modify much in it, the whole login thing works if I directly do a HTML FORM POST from server1 to directly server2 (using action=verify.php link)

But for various reasons and security purposes aswell as executing additional code, I need to use curl or some other way to POST the login.

My login system is working as I can echo the status that login info is correct and login function worked on server2 in my logs, but for some reason (probably due to curl) the cookie isnt getting set/saved to user's PC and so when he visits the server2 url, he still sees "Login Required" error message I have set and therefore isnt getting autologgedin via that login.php file.

This is my login.php code (server1) and $hostname is link to server2 (verify.php)

```
$data['username']=$username;
$data['pass']=$pass;

//open connection
    $ch = curl_init();

    //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $hostname);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)");
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
//curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    //execute post
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    print_r(curl_error($ch));
    print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));
    print_r(curl_errno($ch));

    //close connection
    curl_close($ch);
```

This is the curl response

```
Trying to login with *user* and *pass* Var check username password
 SuccessArray ( [url] => *hostname* [content_type] => text/html [http_code] => 200 [header_size] => 712 [request_size] => 308 [filetime] => -1 [ssl_verify_result] => 0 [redirect_count] => 0 [total_time] => 0.245843 
[namelookup_time] => 0.010171 [connect_time] => 0.01039 [pretransfer_time] => 0.010398 [size_upload] => 257 [size_download] => 93 [speed_download] => 378 [speed_upload] => 1045 [download_content_length] => -1 [upload_content_length] => 257 [starttransfer_time] => 
0.042541 [redirect_time] => 0 [certinfo] => Array ( ) [redirect_url] => ) 0
```

PS: Its not a remote login system for php use, its a system for user login instead of directly using HTML FORM action

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I really hope those aren't a real log in and password. You should **** them out if they are.
In any case, you may need to parse the headers from the response. Look for Set-Cookie headers. The problem is, most browsers don't allow you to just pass those along to the user for a different domain than the one they are on, unless they are accessing a remote resource on that server.

Comment: ofcourse they are not, thats the reason I have used * * to mark it

I didnt quite get what you meant by that as I am still a starter in all this, but is there a way to save the cookie.txt to the accessing user itself ? Or something similar

Comment: More detail on what @Mark is saying: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: that may/maynot work as the url for server2 will be different or subdomain of server1, actually I even just read on another post that we cant save cookies as curl is kind of server-server browser while what I want is user->server->server->user kind of flow. I hope someone can help me a bit more on this, or if I can make an API to do this process for sending Login POST data to a remote verify.php file to login

Comment: When *your server* sends login details to server #2, it won't *log in user* there, it will log in your server #1. You could create temporary session on server #2 and pass to user some hash, based on it and user's ip you can recognize him on server #2.

Comment: That wont work for my use, let me explain a bit more what I am doing. My backend and its own login system is on server2. But I wanted to use my own login form and stuff on my html frontend site so I made it on server1. Another reason is that the same server2 system will be later on on many servers, so which server user exists on and its url I will fetch from mysql on server1 login.php itself. Thats also one of the reasons I am doing it in a roundabout way rather then direct html POST usage as I feel it may be a bit insecure too....... Can anyone suggest me if I can make a API for this ?

Comment: Well I suppose SAML comes to mind.  Seems over engineering perhaps though.  https://developers.google.com/google-apps/sso/saml_reference_implementation

Comment: Well for that purpose I can use openid or SSO as you said, and if all fails I will have to rely on it but if possible I wanted the login system to be selfhosted and custom...... I am also thinking to actually try making a php API for this if possible, dunno where/how to start though, anyways, lets see for 24 hours more if someone has any ideas or answers for the initial question, as after searching around it seems its not possible via curl

Answer (score 0):

**Server configuration begin**

Step 1:

Browse and open:
..\php\php.ini

Step 2:

Uncomment the following line in your php.ini file by removing the semicolon (;).

```
;extension=php_curl.dll
```

After that it will look something like something below-
extension=php_curl.dll

Step 3:

Restart your Apache server.

**Serwer Configuration end**

**php code**

```
$c = curl_init();//init
curl_setopt($c,CURLOPT_URL,'http://yourURL.php');//url 
curl_setopt($c,CURLOPT_POST,1);//post
//1 = true
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,'name=XXX&lastname=YYY');
curl_exec($c);//exec
```

**static option:**

`CURLOPT_URL` - url

`CURLOPT_HEADER` - get header? (0/1)

`CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` - answer serwer to value? (0/1)

`CURLOPT_TIMEOUT` - how long connect, when server is busy

`CURLOPT_POST` - POST? (0/1)

`CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` - POST data

`CURLOPT_NOBODY` - return only HEAD

[more](http://pl.php.net/manual/pl/function.curl-setopt.php)